# howto use gitpython repo.archive() for a tag

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have to export a specific path of a tag. 
The git command is `git archive <tag>` 
but I didn't found a possibility to do this with gitpython

I've tried

```
repo.archive(tar, "<tag>")
```

without luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import git
import os.path

repopath = '/path/to/repo'
repo = git.Repo(repopath)
repo.git.archive('<tag>', '-o', '<tag>.zip')
if os.path.exists('<tag>.zip'):
    pass
```

You can translate almost all git commands to `repo.git.<cmd>(arg0, arg1, ...)`. Need to replace `-` in the command name with `_`.

```
git log --oneline    ->    output = repo.git.log('--oneline')
git commit --allow-empty -m "foo bar" ->  output = repo.git.commit('--allow-empty', '-m', 'foo bar')
git ls-tree -r -t HEAD -> output = repo.git.ls_tree('-r', '-t', 'HEAD')
```